# natbib error: \providecommand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers

Tags: citing, natbib

I have a problem with natbib using plainnat.

The error in aux file:
\providecommand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers

Errors shown in the issues of TeXstudio:

Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...and\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers
Author undefined for citation`avgerinos2017team' (natbib) on page 4

I already checked that all year inputs are there.

#Packages I loaded

```
%Packages
\usepackage[margin=1.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, calc, paralist, mdwlist, array, tabularx, bbm}
\RequirePackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace, graphicx, verbatim, eurosym, epstopdf, hyperref, pdflscape}
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}} % disappears the blue boxes on links
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dcolumn, rotating, float, longtable, ragged2e}
\usepackage[font=normalsize]{caption}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\newcommand\expt[2]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{E}\left[#1\middle|#2‌​\right]}
\newcommand\coex[2]{\E\mleft[\,#1\;\middle|\;#2\,\mright]}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bm}
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67}
\usepackage[round, sort, numbers, authoryear]{natbib}
%\setcitestyle{authoryear}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.55}}
```

## Sample bib (produced by JabRef)

```
@Article{reagans2005individual,
  author    = {Reagans, Ray and Argote, Linda and Brooks, Daria},
  journal   = {Management science},
  title     = {Individual experience and experience working together: Predicting learning rates from knowing who knows what and knowing how to work together},
  year      = {2005},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {869--881},
  volume    = {51},
  groups    = {ghs},
  publisher = {INFORMS},
}

@Article{avgerinos2017team,
  author    = {Avgerinos, Emmanouil and Gokpinar, Bilal},
  journal   = {Manufacturing \& Service Operations Management},
  title     = {Team familiarity and productivity in cardiac surgery operations: The effect of dispersion, bottlenecks, and task complexity},
  year      = {2017},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {19--35},
  volume    = {19},
  groups    = {ghs},
  publisher = {INFORMS},
}
```

Comment: In fact, I could get rid of the error by getting rid of option author year from loading the package `natbib` and inserted `\setcitestyle{authoryear}` under it.

Comment: Contrary to what the error message says, `avgerinos2017team` has a well-defined author field. Delete the `.aux` and `.bbl` files (if on Overleaf, clear the cache: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache) and recompile.

Comment: You don't want both `authoryear` and `numbers` in `\usepackage[round, sort, numbers, authoryear]{natbib}`: You should pick one of the two.

Comment: @moewe I think that second error is caused by the earlier error with natbib. Also, thank you so much for your comment on the options for natbib. That makes so much sense and I don't know how I didn't think about it. thank you again!